# Reporting Services WS from Java - Getting (401)Unauthorized

Tags: java, web-services, reporting-services, unauthorized

We're writing a web application that is trying to replace all ReportManager functionality using calls to Reporting Services SOAP API.

We started working with SSRS 2008 and had our Java code working correctly.  We've since had to downgrade to SSRS 2005 and now we're having problems connecting to the Server to get the list of reports available.

We make the following call:

catalog = _reportingService.listChildren(_reportCredentials.getFolder(), false);

which returns an exception - (401)Unauthorized

_reportCredentials just holds information from a properties file (like the folder to use, the username and password, etc.).  _reportService is defined as:

private ReportingService2005Soap _reportingService;

...

_reportingServiceLocator = new ReportingService2005Locator();
_reportingServiceLocator.setReportingService2005SoapEndpointAddress(soapURL);

try {

_reportingService = _reportingServiceLocator.getReportingService2005Soap();

} catch (Exception e) {
                throw new ReportServicesException("Could not retrieve SOAP Reporting Service.");
            }

I can also connect to ReportManager as the user/password we're connecting with in the code.

All of the 'documentation' I can find is just .NET code that doesn't seem to apply to the Java code.  Has anybody experienced problems like this, or know of a good resource for Java developers using these services?

Answer (score 1):

We traced the problem back to having SSRS 2005 installed on Windows Server 2008.  Following the steps here: http://www.omegaprojex.com/index.php/2008/10/10/ssrs-2005-on-windows-server-2008/ fixed our problem.